# Angular2 Teradata Covalent Data Table rowSelect Issue

Tags: angular, teradata

I have an Angular2 web app using Teradata Covalent Data Table component with data pagination and row selection enabled. The data is being pulled via REST api in small chunks as opposed to all rows at once, so row selections are not automatically rendering during back and forth pagination. i.e. if I select a row on page 1, then navigate to page 2 and then back to page 1 the selected row on page 1 is not highlighted.

I'm not sure if this can be handled by a template entry in the blah.component.html file or if I need to do something in the blah.component.ts (TypeScript) file.

I'm keeping track of selected row unique id's in a numeric array as rows are selected and deselected. In the .ts file --> selectedItems: number[];

Here's the html code for the data table:

```
<td-data-table [data]="items.content" [columns]="columns" [sortable]="true" [sortBy]="sortBy" [sortOrder]="sortOrder" [selectable]="true" [multiple]="true" (sortChange)="sort($event)" (rowSelect)="selectRow($event)" (selectAll)="selectAllRows($event)">
<template tdDataTableTemplate="matchCount" let-value="value" let-row="row" let-column="column">
    <div layout="row">
        <span flex>{{value | number:0}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
<template tdDataTableTemplate="itemSize" let-value="value" let-row="row" let-column="column">
    <div layout="row">
        <span flex>{{value | bytes}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: try to add [(ngModel)]="selectedRows" in <td-data-table> and this array will automatically add and remove selected row from array. and its work fine if you are not doing server side pagination. i haven't check this server side pagination.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response Vinay. I actually added that exact code snippet soon after I posted this question, with mixed results. The selected rows are indeed being added to and tracked in the 'selectedRows' variable now, but the UI is not updating with information with previous selections when paging back and forth. I'm wondering if it's because we're loading a small subset of data with each page event instead of paging through a full set of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reached out to the gitter Teradata/covalent chat group and they were able to help me out. You simply have to loop through the values in selectedRows and the values in the new data set to look for any matches. If a match is found, just remove it from selectedRows with .splice and add it back in from the data set. In effect it's just manually updating the ngmodel.

`this.selectedRows.splice(parseInt(x),1,this.newRow.content[y]);`